# How can we insert a sequence of integers into a binary search tree using recursion?

Tags: sorting, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am trying to write a recursive function that implements BST. However I am facing a number of issues that I am unable to solve.

For a start, I want my function to insert the item located in the middle index of the array "arr[]" into the BST "t" at every recursion. But, I don't know what the general case should be. I tried to implement this logic but I am getting all wrong outputs.

So my question is, where am I wrong and what should I do to create a suitable general case for this recursive function?

MY CODE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCSg.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you. Please read also [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to build a BST that contains the elements of a sorted list. It would be good in future to specify the problem you're trying to solve more carefully.

If I've guessed correctly, the algorithm needs to return the root of the new BST.

The intuition you want comes from the structure of a BST:  The subtrees of any node are themselves BSTs.

So suppose we make the BST creator a function that can operate on any chunk of the sorted input list and turn it into a BST.

Something like this:

```
def build_bst(elements: List[int], first_index: int, last_index: int) -> Node:
```

Now we can use the intuition about BST structure.

The algorithm uses `first_index` and `last_index` in some simple arithmetic to get the index `m` of an element near the middle the chunk.  `elements[m]` becomes the data in a newly created node. This will be the root of the BST. Then note that elements `first_index` to `m - 1` must be in the left subtree of the new node. `m + 1` to `last_index` must be in the right subtree. Use recursive calls to build those subtrees, assigning the return values as left and right children of the new node. Then return the node.

That's about it for the general recursion. I'll let you work out the base case and how to initiate the recursion.

nb: You can get rid of the index parameters if you're willing to actually compute the chunks as standalone lists. This will look elegant, but a real implementation is likely to require extra copying, depending on language and programming techniques. The way I've shown here is more generally useful.